# AVG Scan Results

Tags: 12.04, directory

I'm new in Ubuntu World.I have installed Avg 2013 on my Ubuntu LTS 12.04.
I'm using only the command line scanner. I would like to access the results summary (scan profile), after scanning the disk, and copy them in a txt.

Having tried access avgvlog file but doesn't display the summary...
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-r` option with `avgscan` to save your report into a text file.

For example

```
 avgscan /directory/to/scan -r report.txt
```

It will store your scan summery in the `report.txt` file with all relevant details.

From `man avgscan`

```
   -r FILE, --report FILE
          Save scan report to specified file.
```